# Is the field "debugger" protected in javascript objects in some browsers?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, object, safari, debugging

I have written a javascript that works well in all browser except Internet Explorer and Safari. In both browsers there is a syntax error, and Safari even tells me the exact line of that error:

```
(function($)
{
    Astrups.debugger = // This line!
    {
```

The variable Astrups was defined as such earlier in the script:

```
var Astrups = {};
```

Any ideas? Thanks

---

I should perhaps mention the error messager. Safari tells me:

> SyntaxError: Parse error

And internet explorer simply complains that Astrups in undefined in the HTML file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `debugger` is a keyword which acts as a debugger breakpoint.

Write `debugger;` in your code and IE will always break while real browsers will only break if a debugger (e.g. Firebug) is active.

Comment: What are my options? Is there a way to fix this from "the source", or must I change the name of the object and fix every referral?

Comment: i'd recommend you change the property name to something else. While `debugger` is not a reserved word in JavaScript you should treat it as one because most browsers will identify it as a breakpoint label.

Comment: Yes, change it or use the array subscript syntax (`Astrups['debugger']`) - but I'd rather change it.